# When I use mvn run spring boot test occur OOM

Tags: spring-boot, out-of-memory

When I use mvn run spring boot test occur OOM, the message as below

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

When I remove the spring annotations, the test running well.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```